# NetworkX: Subgraph Isomorphism by edge and node attributes

Tags: python, networkx, subgraph, isomorphism

Suppose I have 2 graphs A and B and I want to know if A is a subgraph of B.
The nodes contain attributes, say, 'size' and 'material'.

When I run:

```
GM = networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(B,A)
print networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.subgraph_is_isomorphic()
```

This only matches graph by edges only and not by edges and attribute.

Any clue on how check attributes?

Also, suppose B contains 2 connected graphs of A.

When I run:

```
GM.mapping
```

This will output only 1 of the subgraphs of A. Any idea on how to output every subgraph?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've solved this by using:

```
print GM = iso.GraphMatcher(B,A,node_match=iso.categorical_node_match(['material', 'size'],['metal',1]))
```

What I didn't know before is that `['metal',1]` is just a default and not a hard match.

Comment: Can you explain the "default" value? I'm not sure how it will be used in the function.

Comment: @jim-raynor If a node in the graph does not have a value for the attribute (i.e. the attribute isn't assigned),  then the "default" value given above is taken as the default for such nodes. You could pass `None` if you are uncomfortable assuming attributes for nodes that shouldn't have them.

Comment: And yes the syntax is a bit confusing/(not-straightforward). Even I thought it was some kind of hard match but couldn't wrap my head around why someone would want that. Eventually, I did find the explanation after little digging.

Answer (score 6):

You can iterate over all possible subgraphs in the following way

```
GM = networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(B,A)
for subgraph in GM.subgraph_isomorphisms_iter():
    print subgraph
```

subgraph in this example is a dictionary that maps nodes of B to nodes of A.

For the question of attribute matching, drum's suggestion has worked for me. Additional attribute matching actually speeds up things significantly for large graphs.