# How to match subgraphs with edge attributes in networkx correctly?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, isomorphism

I'm new to subgraph matching and I found that `networkx` has a pretty convenient way to do that. However I'm not sure how to match subgraphs correctly on graphs with edge attributes.

For example, say I have the following graph that has edge attributes:

```
import networkx as nx
import networkx.algorithms.isomorphism as iso

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, label="A")
G.add_edge(1, 2, label="D")
G.add_edge(2, 1, label="B")
G.add_edge(2, 3, label="C")
```

And I'm trying to find a subgraph with the following structure:

```
SG = nx.MultiDiGraph()
SG.add_edge(5, 6)
SG.add_edge(6, 7)
```

Note that this subgraph does not have edge attribute so I was trying to find the subgraphs with any edges that fits the node structure (in this case a simple path of length 2). I found these 2 SO questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671522/networkx-subgraph-isomorphism-by-edge-and-node-attributes), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696334/networkx-matcher-for-subgraph-isomorphism)) which directed me to try the following 2 approaches:

**Approach 1**

```
gm = iso.MultiDiGraphMatcher(G, SG, edge_match=iso.categorical_edge_match("label", None))
print(gm.subgraph_is_monomorphic())

for subgraph_x in gm.subgraph_monomorphisms_iter():
    print(subgraph_x)
```

This prints:

```
True
{1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7}
```

However, I assumed that this will print two different subgraphs since there are 2 different edges between the nodes 1 and 2. Meaning, the two subgraphs should be `((1,2)  with edge label "A", (2,3) with edge label "C"), and ((1,2) with edge label "D", (2,3) with edge label "C")`. I also couldn't find an approach to output which edge labels correspond to the output nodes which would have helped understand which path this ouputs.

**Approach 2**

```
SG = nx.MultiDiGraph()
SG.add_edge(5, 6, label="A")
SG.add_edge(6, 7, label="C")

gm = iso.MultiDiGraphMatcher(G, SG, edge_match=lambda x, y: x[0]['label'] == y[0]['label'])
print(gm.subgraph_is_monomorphic())
for subgraph_x in gm.subgraph_monomorphisms_iter():
    print(subgraph_x)
```

This prints

```
True
{1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7}
```

Here I specified which edges I want in the subgraph and the output makes sense, since there is only 1 subgraph with that structure. For example, if I change `SG.add_edge(6, 7, label="C")` to `SG.add_edge(6, 7, label="D")`, this prints `False`.

**However, for my use case I need the first approach to work, since my input is a subgraph without edge attributes.**

I also tried using a graph without edge attributes and changing between `subgraph_isomorphisms_iter` and `subgraph_monomorphisms_iter`:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph([(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,4), (4,5), (5,6), (1,7), (7,8)])
subgraph = nx.MultiDiGraph([(10,20), (10,30), (10,40), (40,50)])

subgraphs = []
GM = iso.MultiDiGraphMatcher(G,subgraph,edge_match=iso.categorical_edge_match([],[]))
for subgraph_x in GM.subgraph_monomorphisms_iter():
    subgraphs.append(subgraph_x)
subgraphs
```

using `subgraph_monomorphisms_iter` this prints:

```
[{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50},
 {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 7: 40, 8: 50},
 {1: 10, 2: 20, 4: 30, 7: 40, 8: 50},
 {1: 10, 2: 20, 7: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50},
 {1: 10, 3: 20, 2: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50},
 {1: 10, 3: 20, 2: 30, 7: 40, 8: 50},
 {1: 10, 3: 20, 4: 30, 7: 40, 8: 50},
 {1: 10, 3: 20, 7: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50},
 {1: 10, 4: 20, 2: 30, 7: 40, 8: 50},
 {1: 10, 4: 20, 3: 30, 7: 40, 8: 50},
 {1: 10, 7: 20, 2: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50},
 {1: 10, 7: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50}]
```

Which seems to be very redundant as there should only be 3 subgraphs, but even using `subgraph_isomorphisms_iter` it seems to find 2 which are redundant:

```
subgraphs = []
GM = nx.algorithms.isomorphism.DiGraphMatcher(G,subgraph) #dictionary that maps nodes of main graph to nodes of subgraph.
for subgraph_x in GM.subgraph_isomorphisms_iter():
    subgraphs.append(subgraph_x)
```

This prints

```
[{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 7: 40, 8: 50}, {1: 10, 3: 20, 2: 30, 7: 40, 8: 50}]
```

However, when I tried switching the first 2 approaches to `subgraph_isomorphisms_iter` it didn't find any subgraphs. So i'm very confused.

**Update**
I found that [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820193/networkx-digraphmatcher-returns-no-results-on-directed-graphs) explains the difference between isomorphism and monomorphism in networkx well. And found the [source code](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/8594a68e3e9ee3a373fe626b0ab1176023acb17f/networkx/algorithms/isomorphism/vf2userfunc.py#L121) for the matcher if that helps. It also seems from [here](https://groups.google.com/g/networkx-discuss/c/cMrNcUP8Jp4) that the redundancy is a result of symmetries and if I understand correctly networkx doesn't take symmetries into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach:

Expand MultiDiGraph to DiGraph, perform isomorphism check on expanded DiGraph, this way you account for multiple edges as they are counted seperately:

```
import networkx as nx
import networkx.algorithms.isomorphism as iso

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, label="A")
G.add_edge(1, 2, label="D")
G.add_edge(2, 1, label="B")
G.add_edge(2, 3, label="C")

SG = nx.MultiDiGraph()
SG.add_edge(5, 6)
SG.add_edge(6, 7)

def expand_graph(G):
    '''
    Expand the graph such that for each edge e from u to v:
    e=(u,v) you create an edge specific vertex: e -> (u,e_)(e_,u)
    This way your MultiDiGraph becomes a DiGraph
    '''
    H = nx.DiGraph()
    for u in G.nodes():
        key = 0
        for e in G.out_edges(u, data=True):
            H.add_edge(u, str(u)+'_out_'+str(key))
            H.add_edge(str(u)+'_out_'+str(key), e[1])
            key+=1
            
    nx.set_node_attributes(H, {n:0 for n in H.nodes()}, 'original')
    nx.set_node_attributes(H, {n:1 for n in G.nodes()}, 'original')
    return H

def collapse_graph(G_):
    '''
    Turns a DiGraph generated with the expand_graph function back 
    to a MultiDiGraph, adds edge attribtute label to distinguish edges
    '''
    H = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    for u, d  in G_.nodes(data=True):
        if d['original']==1:
            for u, e_ in G_.out_edges(u):
                for e_, v in G_.out_edges(e_):
                    H.add_edge(u, v, label = e_.split('_')[-1])
    return H

G_ = expand_graph(G)
SG_ = expand_graph(SG)

subgraphs = []
GM = nx.algorithms.isomorphism.DiGraphMatcher(G_,SG_) 

#Perform the check solely for isomorph subgraphs, 
#note this includes also isomorph subgraphs on the set of vertices e_
for subgraph_x in GM.subgraph_isomorphisms_iter():
    subgraphs.append(subgraph_x)

result=[]
subgraphs_valid = []

#This gets rid of subgraphs that are isomorph but not on the right set of nodes,
#i.e. we want to check whether the nodes are of mixed type (e_ mixed with u)
    
for s in subgraphs:
    if all([True if type(u)== type(v) else False for u,v in s.items()]):
        subgraphs_valid.append(s)
        
#Iterate over the isomorph subgraphs, extract the subgraphs and parse them as results
#Collapse them in order to get a edge representations with labels for the edges

for s in subgraphs_valid:  
    f = [k for k, v in s.items()]
    F_ = G_.subgraph(f)
    F = collapse_graph(F_)
    result.append(list(F.edges(data=True)))
    
print(result)
```

I am sure there is an easier solution... But maybe the approach helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still going over it and testing a few things, but one question I have is about the labels. The output of this seems to be: `[[(1, 2, {'label': '0'}), (2, 3, {'label': '1'})], [(1, 2, {'label': '1'}), (2, 3, {'label': '1'})]]`, how can I get the original edge labels? That is, instead of `(1, 2, {'label': '0'})` output (1, 2, {'label': 'A'})

Comment: I also find that this have the same issue with the duplicates. For example, if my inputs are: `G = nx.MultiDiGraph([(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (4,5), (5,6), (1,7), (7,8), (8,9)])` and 
`SG = nx.MultiDiGraph([(10,20), (10,30), (10,40), (10,70), (70,80), (80,90)])`. The results have 12 subgraphs, which should only be 2 I believe. For example: `result[0]` and `result[2]` print the same thing: `[(1, 2, {'label': '0'}), (1, 3, {'label': '1'}), (1, 4, {'label': '2'}), (1, 7, {'label': '3'}), (4, 5, {'label': '0'}), (5, 6, {'label': '0'})]`

Comment: Though I find that a simple solution to the duplicates is just to create a function that takes the results, and create a new list which append each item from the result if it's not there already. Though I imagine that the duplicates can take a lot of space with larger graph so I'm not sure if there's a better solution to filter the duplicates before